# Pour, afin de, en vue de

Tags: grammaire, expressions

J’ai constaté plusieurs utilisations des constructions « pour, afin de, dans le but de, en vue de...», qu'on peut utiliser pour expliquer le but, mais quelle est la différence entre elles ?

Je vous serais reconnaissant pour quelques exemples de chaque cas.

Comment: Vous aurez beaucoup d’exemples sur ce site : https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pour — 
https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/afin%20de — 
https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/but (2ème onglet subst.masc.) C 2 b (+ Rem [remarques connues par 1% des francophones]) — https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vue (3ème onglet subst.fém.) A 3 a ẞ

Answer (score 2):

Je peux vous donner un début de réponse tiré de l'usage courant en France.

"afin de", "dans le but de" et "en vue de" sont quasiment substituables entre eux. Il y a une petite exception pour "en vue de". Si on met un verbe derrière il est identique aux autres, mais si on met un nom, il n'est plus interchangeable. Par exemple "en vue de me repentir" peut être remplacé par "afin de me repentir" mais "en vue de ma rédemption" ne peut **pas** être remplacé par "afin de ma rédemption".
Ces trois expressions expriment un seul sens de "pour" (qui lui en contient plusieurs autres): le sens d'expliquer les objectifs d'un acte ou d'un objet :

*"je suis venu ici pour vous tuer"* a strictement le même sens que *"je suis venu ici afin de vous tuer"*, *"je suis venu ici dans le but de vous tuer"* ou *"je suis venu ici en vue de vous tuer"*.
Pour l'objectif d'un objet (sa raison d'être) c'est un peu plus flou. Il y a, j'ai l'impression, une petite subtilité entre dire *"ce bijou est fait pour plaire aux jeunes filles"* et *"ce bijou est fait dans le but de plaire aux jeunes filles"*. Dans le second cas c'est sûr que le bijou a été fait dans un but précis : celui de plaire aux jeunes filles. Dans le premier cas, on frôle la figure de style et la phrase peut vouloir dire que le bijou plait tellement aux jeunes filles qu'on a l'impression qu'il a été fait pour ça.

Maintenant voici des exemples d'usages de "pour" où `afin de/dans le but de/en vue de` ne peuvent **en aucun cas** s'y substituer.

- La destination : *"le train pour Toulouse"*, *"ce cadeau est pour Marie"*, *"j'ai voté pour lui"*
- L'échange : *"j'ai eu ce foulard pour trois euros"*, *"oeil pour oeil, dent pour dent"*
- L'attribution : *"il m'a pris pour un autre"*, *"il est passé pour un imbécile"*
- Le dates/échéances :  *"ce sera prêt pour le 15 Mai"*, *"le dossier doit être terminé pour demain"*
- L'adhésion : *"je suis pour"*, *"êtes vous pour ou contre cette loi ?"*
- La cause : *"je viens combattre pour mon honneur"*
- La conséquence : *"il est trop faible pour se lever"*

En résumé, dans les multiples sens de *pour* (consultables ici: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour), "en vue de, afin de, dans le but de" ne recouvrent (quasiment) que le sens III.A mais par contre ils sont (quasiment) équivalents entre eux.